# Neural Network Design Challenge

Tags: computability, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-networks, pattern-recognition

i'm studying for PHD Entrance Exam on Stanford. one of previous material exam designed very challenging.

i want to design a NN for classifying following 2-class problem.

1) output should be -1 or 1.

2) output should be 0 or 1.

[image]

for sove this question i think using XOR neural network for following problem for above dataset? i'm not sure because one point under the X-axis in this picture and above data all is above X-axis?
can anyone help me ?

[image]

i want to draw a NN for two case mentioned above and find minimum number of node (without input node).
for example i think for 0 or 1 output we have following NN with (5 nodes and 2 input node)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Artificial Neural Network design is as much art as it is science. Art in the sense that many problems have varying approaches and designs which may **not** be uniquely characterized.

After this simple prologue, this is a generalisation of the ANN XOR problem which multi-level ANNs have been shown to solve eficiently.

It can also be seen as transformation of the original XOR problem (simply rotate the data by $\pi/4$) and *explosion* by a factor.

Usually ANNs employ 3 layers (1-input 1 -intermediate and 1-output), of course more layers can be added. This simply illustrates a trade-off between computational power versus computational complexity.

By the [universal approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) arbitrary (compact) mappings can be approximated by a (sufficiently complex) MLP ANN .

A further approach is to use a hidden layer with $2n$ or $2^n$ neurons (by symmetry of the problem) and experiment with that.

UPDATE:

As per the OP's further comments regarding transformations between variables $\in \{0,1\}$ to variables $\in \{-1,1\}$, a [link for an MLP ANN for the XOR problem using -1,1 values](http://www.di.unito.it/~botta/didattica/FNN.pdf)

Comment: thanks Nikos. Dear Nickos, can i say we can using a ANN with 3 node at minimum? (2 input + 3 other nodes) we can correctly classify such data?

Comment: @user17973, unfortunately i cannot tell, i will have to try it specifically, but i have the feeling it will need an *even* number of hidden neurons to achieve the $\pi/4$ rotation.. hope this helps you

Comment: @user17973 On the other hand it is known that the [XOR problem](http://www.mind.ilstu.edu/curriculum/artificial_neural_net/xor_problem_and_solution.php?modGUI=239&compGUI=1286&itemGUI=2253) uses an even number of hidden neurons, so since the data here can be *pre-rotated* and then fed into an XOR MLP, same conjecture follows

Comment: infact i want to find minimum number of node (wihtout input node) for implementation :) 1) for -1 or 1 output we have (2 input nodes + 3 another nodes) 2) for 0 or 1 output we have (2 input + 5 output ). i dont know am i right ?

Comment: @user17973, sorry dont think i follow, what exactly do you mean by "*nodes*", the number of nodes/neurons on the hidden layer? if yes my previous comments tried to answer that, maybe sth else? (note encoding is not so much of an issue as far as i can tell, since any bias term can be added in the output node)

Comment: i means for 0 or 1 output we have exactly XOR problem. but for -1 or 1 output we can have neural network with remove 2 nodes. am i clear? i add some detail to my question for clarity

Comment: @user17973, you should edit the question, instead you edited my answer :), nodes can have arbitrary weights and also arbitarty bias terms, so in this sense any variable $X  \in \{0,1\}$ can be transformed into a variable $Y=(b-a)X+a  \in \{a,b\}$

Comment: i'm sorry for my wrong editing. ok, at last my previous inference is correct? 1) for 0 or 1 output for above question we need 5 node. 2) for -1 or 1 output problem would be simpler and solve with 3 node?

Comment: @user17973, no i dont think so, in fact this *may* be correct but it is not necessary, a main difference between XOR and the problem stated is the number of data (which is **not** the same), thus the actual NN weights can be different, but anyway the previous comment gave a way to tarnsform any variable in {0,1} to another variable in {a,b}, a [link for XOR MLP using -1,1 values](http://www.di.unito.it/~botta/didattica/FNN.pdf)

Comment: i think some modification to my question needed. infact i want draw a NN with Minimum node to classify such data (without input node) for 1) output 0 or 1 2) -1 or 1  . i think my answer is 5 (for 1) and 3 Node (for 2).